# call c++ function from java without changing c++ code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to use some `.cpp` class and methods in my java program. For example, I have `p1.java` that calls `method1`. `method1` is available in `p2.cpp` and `p2.cpp` includes `p3.cpp`. I don't want to change cpp codes...

Is it possible? (and I need `.cpp` and `.header` both.)

And is there any alternative better solution? (except java native interface)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create an extra layer between Java and C++ with JNI - effectively you create:

```
method1_java_cpp_layer( JNIEnv * e, jobject o )
{
    extracted_information = extract_information( e, o );
    method1( extracted_information )
}
```

And this goes into "java_cpp_layer.cpp".

Comment: Thank's... . I did that. But now when i run program(java  java_cpp_layer) I get  another error:libjava_cpp_layer.so: undefined symbol: p2 ...Can you help me?